# offline cache in webapp is not working in fullscreen

Tags: manifest, offline

I have a webapp done with jqtouch and the offline cache is not working when I add it to the homescreen as a fullscreen app, I finally found out what was causing the app not to cache, it was when I added it to the homescreen in fullscreen with

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

that it didn´t work.

If I remove the tag then the cache is working!

Any suggestion really appreciated since I need my app to be in fullscreen.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is less of an answer, but I've been fighting with the same problem for a while, without a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564399/offline-webapp-on-ios7-stops-working-after-export-to-home-screen

Your workaround seems at least promising, are you using IOS7?